# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2n+2}}{x^2-2x+2}\,{\rm d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2n+2}}{x^2-2x+2} \,{\rm d}x \tag{1}$$

This integral came up as a result of another integral I was trying to evaluate. Just for recreational purposes. Is there some closed form for this, even in terms of special functions?

In general, is it possible to evaluate integrals of the form:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{P(x,x^n)}{Q(x)} \,{\rm d}x \tag{2}$$

with $\text{deg}(P) > \deg(Q)$? For example:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{1+x^2} \,{\rm d}x \tag{3}$$

can be written in terms of the digamma function. If I'm not mistaken, $(1)$ does not follow from $(3)$, because if you try to complete the square in the denominator of $(1)$, you'd end up having to perform a $u$-sub with $u = x-1$ and then a $(u+1)^{2n+2}$ in the numerator. This ruins things.

Can someone give some help?

Comment: Edited. Thank you

Comment: To apply (3) to (1) you'd want $u=1-x$ (so the bounds don't change), and then you're forced to live with binomial-expanding the top probably.

Comment: This is what I thought about, but I'm assuming this won't help to evaluate the integral. I will give it a whirl.

Comment: Do polynomial division with remainder.  You will get a polynomial of degree $2n$, which you can integrate, plus the integral of a linear term divided by your quadratic denominator.  That is a standard form that yields to a trig substitution.  Expressing the denominator as $(x-1)^2+1$ indicates a tangent substitution.

Comment: You can always write $P(x,x^n)$ as $P_0(x)+P_1(x)x^n+P_2(x)x^{2n}+\cdots$. So the integral can be split into $\sum \int P_k(x)/Q(x)\, x^{kn}\,{\rm d}x$. Then you can do partial fractions on the $P_k/Q$s to split further into a linear combination of integrals of the form $\int x^{an+b} {\rm d}x$, $\int x^m /(x-a) {\rm d}x$, $\int x^m / (x^2+ax+b) {\rm d}x$. By substitution the latter two can be turned into multiples of $\int (x+1)^m\tfrac{{\rm d}x}{x}$ and $\int (x+a)^m\tfrac{{\rm d}x}{x^2+1}$.

Comment: @runway44 I am not quite understanding what you mean by the second line of this. Can you explain further? Ross, You suggest doing polynomial division. I have attempted this. Are you suggesting that this resultant polynomial of degree $2n$ has some closed form? I've calculated the first 4 terms and can't seem to find a pattern in the coefficients.

Comment: Split the numerator $P(x,x^n)$ into a sum as I said, divide each term by $Q(x)$, then split the integral up (because integration is linear). That is the meaning of my second sentence.

Comment: Also pro-tip, it's helpful to include non-LaTeX in your question titles so others have the normal right-click menu available to them when your question shows up in lists on the site.

Comment: I've never thought about this. I will do this in the future.  Edited.Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like most things in life, this is a hypergeometric integral:

$$
\fbox{$\frac{(1+i) \left(\, _2F_1\left(1,2 n+3;2
   (n+2);\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)-i \,
   _2F_1\left(1,2 n+3;2
   (n+2);\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)\right)}{8
   n+12}\text{ if }\Re(n)>-\frac{3}{2}$}
$$
The way to get it there is to transform $[0, 1]$ to $[0, \infty]$ by a linear fractional, and then it looks like a standard hypergeometric integral (I did not do that, but just asked mathematica).

Answer (score 4):

Let's first try to find a simple expression for $ I_{k} $, defined for all $ k\in\mathbb{N} $, as follows : \begin{aligned}I_{k}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{k}}{x^{2}+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\end{aligned}

Let $ k\in\mathbb{N} $. Using the geometric formula for partial sums, we have : $$ \frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{1+x^{2}}+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}{\left(-1\right)^{k-1-j}x^{2j}}=\frac{x^{2k}}{1+x^{2}} $$

Thus : $$ I_{2k}=\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{\pi}{4}+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1-j}}{1+2j}} $$

And : $$ I_{2k+1}=\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{\ln{2}}{2}-\sum_{j=1}^{k}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-j+1}}{2j}} $$

Now let $ n\in\mathbb{N} $, let's get back to the original integral : \begin{aligned} \int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^{2n+2}}{x^{2}-2x+2}\,\mathrm{d}x}&=\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^{2n+2}}{\left(1-x\right)^{2}+1}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\ &=\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\left(1-x\right)^{2n+2}}{x^{2}+1}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\ &=\sum_{k=0}^{2n+2}{\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{2n+2}{k}I_{k}} \\ &=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}{\binom{2n+2}{2k}I_{2k}}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{2n+2}{2k+1}I_{2k+1}}\end{aligned}

We have all the formulas we need, we can continue for further possible simplifications, but I think the final formula would seem a little ugly.

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int \frac{x^{2n+2}}{x^2-2x+2}\, dx=\int x^{2n}\frac{x^2}{(x-(1+i)) (x-(1-i))}\, dx$$
$$ \frac{x^2}{(x-(1+i)) (x-(1-i))}=1+\frac{1}{x-(1-i)}+\frac{1}{x-(1+i)}$$ So, we face the problem of
$$I_a=\int \frac{x^{2n}}{x-a}\,dx$$ where $a$ is a complex number.
$$I_a=-\frac{x^{2 n+1} }{a (2 n+1)}\, _2F_1\left(1,2 n+1;2 n+2;\frac{x}{a}\right)$$
$$J_a=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n}}{x-a}\,dx=-\frac{\, _2F_1\left(1,2 n+1;2 n+2;\frac{1}{a}\right)}{(2  n+1)a}$$ As a total
$$K_n=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n+2}}{x^2-2x+2}\, dx=
\frac 1{2n+1}-$$ $$\frac{(1-i) \left(\, _2F_1\left(1,2 n+1;2n+2;\frac{1-i}{2}\right)+i
   \, _2F_1\left(1,2 n+1;2n+2;\frac{1+i}{2}\right)\right)}{2(2 n+1)}$$

Now, depending on the parity of $n$, we have two kinds of results.
$$K_{2m}=(-1) ^m\alpha_m+(-4)^m \,\log(2)$$
$$K_{2m+1}=(-1) ^m\beta_m+(-4)^m\,\pi$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
m & \alpha_m & \beta_m \\
0 & 1 & \frac{10}{3} \\
 1 & \frac{79}{30} & \frac{436}{35} \\
 2 & \frac{14087}{1260} & \frac{174434}{3465} \\
 3 & \frac{3990557}{90090} & \frac{1810840}{9009} \\
 4 & \frac{217474889}{1225224} & \frac{260047122}{323323} \\
 5 & \frac{10326377909}{14549535} & \frac{71767882892}{22309287} \\
 6 & \frac{19001942777579}{6692786100} & \frac{64592068202966}{5019589575} \\
 7 & \frac{3306285643032971}{291136195350} &
   \frac{232272319634479216}{4512611027925}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Hi Claude! Could you edit your answer in the slightest way possible? I thought I upvoted your answer yesterday, but discovered I accidentally downvoted it instead! I'm terribly sorry about this :(

Comment: @AlannRosas. You always can cancel an upvote or a downvote (as far as I know). But, in any manner, don't worry.

Comment: it says that my vote is locked because I placed it 19 hours ago :(

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple, elementary closed-form solution. Note that
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^m}{x-a}dx = I_m=\frac1m +aI_{m-1}
=a^m\ln\frac{a-1}a+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{a^k}{m-k}
$$
and $x^2-2x+2=(x-a)(x-a^*)$, with
$a=\sqrt2 e^{\frac{i\pi}4}$. Then
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\frac{x^{2n+2}}{x^2-2x+2}dx\\
 =& \ \Im\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n+2}}{x-a}dx
= \Im \bigg(a^{2n+2}\ln\frac{a-1}a+\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}\frac{a^k}{2n+2-k}\bigg)\\
= & -2^{n}\bigg(\frac\pi2\sin\frac{n \pi}2+\ln2 \cos\frac{n \pi}2\bigg)+\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\frac{2^{\frac k2}\sin\frac{k\pi}4}{2n+2-k}\\
\end{align}